# Close BottomSheetDialog when Fragment Destroys

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, dialog, fragment

I have a `fragment`, and in some situations it shows a `BottomSheetDialog`. My `fragment` has a `recyclerView` and in its `adapter`, when user clicks on items I show the `dialog`. I want to dismiss the `dialog` when `fragment` destroys.

Comment: please try using interface.

Comment: as per @LokeshDesai comment  Interface is best option.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the below document
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog

This will help u to dismiss the dialog.

Comment: I show the dialog when user long clicks on the items of recycler views. but when user press long on item and dialog is shown,without lifting his finger, he can close the fragment by sliding. I want to dismiss the dialog when the fragment has destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

you can close dialog to write below code on `onPause()`

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
```

Comment: I have no access to the dialog in fragment. I've shown it in adapter

Comment: you can create static dialog and access in fragment, this is temporary solution not a best

Comment: making static dialog is bad practice. Try to use interface